Visual Studio 2022 doesn't recognise and color syntax
Recently I've got new corporate laptop and since then my Visual Studio Professional 2022 fails at recognising and coloring some code syntax. For example classes, methods etc. in text editor are simply black:



Here are some more details and my findings so far:

It's irregular. Within one .cs file some of the syntax may be colored and some not
It impacts both user types and .NET libraries
Sometimes while using the studio screen refreshes and coloring starts/ceases to work
It impacts various project with no difference i.e. old legacy .NET Framework projects, recent .NET 6.0, backend, frontend
Manual setting of coloring doesn't help. Color change can be observed when under coursor but in text editor still black
OS is W10
My teammates use same version of Studio, same projects and no problem. Some people face some challenges with Studio and Intellisene but not with coloring
What I tried so far: clean reinstall of Visual Studio, delete .vs folder, switch light/dark mode, reset all settings, play with various editor settings, update Visual Studio
I also raised a ticket with Microsoft but don't have much hope for their support

Would appreciate any help. Currently the issue is so annoying and disturbing that I had to switch to JetBrains Rider. Ran out of ideas, my last overkill try would be to format drive and resetup entire OS.

Weird. Granny/Eggs but have you tried updating the graphics drivers?

Udpated gpu drivers with fresh install but no luck. RTX A1000 6gb on board. Also disabled integrated Intel Iris to make sure that it runs solely on rtx.

Any VS extensions installed that might interfere with coloring? E.g. R# has an option to use its own coloring

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > "Enable file logging".  Never used it myself, but there ought to be some reason visible why Roslyn keeled over when trying to parse the code.

No extensions installed. At some point I tried to install resherper to see if it helps, but no impact. Enabled file logging! Looks promising, I'm now reviewing it.

Reviewed logs but didn't find anything noticeable. No errors ets. Also compared parts of logs when highlighting worked with the failed one and also no difference.

It turned out that it is actual bug in Visual Studio. MS replied to my ticket. Installed new preview version (17.11) and it works now. Thanks everybody for help. Here is explenation what did they change in roslyn:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/72878

thanks.
Looks like I'm stuck with this error until the (17.11) is officially out...
